# Force setInterval to go to next step in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to force `setInterval` to go to next step like this?:

```
global.timers = [] ;

var index = global.timers.length ;

global.timers[index] = setInterval(()=>{
      // ...
},15000);

// pseudo code 
if (event1 occured)
     global.timers[x].step++ // Don't wait for remained time and go to next tick
```

Comment: It seems that `global.timer` does not have a `step` property.

Comment: No, that's not possible. You can set a variable and use an explicit test in the iteration callback to exercise control like that, but the mechanism itself can only be  started and stopped.

Comment: By "go to next tick" does the OP mean stop the timer, run the function, then start the timer again? Like stop the timer, do whatever intermediate task there is, then continue the interval?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher Imagine that, I need to send an offer to someone and i will wait for a period of time for his reaction, if he/she refused the offer i want to send it to another one but don't wait the remained time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply clear the interval and create it again

```
global.timers = [] ;

var index = global.timers.length ;

global.timers[index] = setInterval(fn,15000);

// pseudo code 
if (event1 occured) {
    clearInterval(global.timers[x]);
    global.timers[index] = setInterval(fn,15000);
}
function fn() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the id in the timers array and extract the event handler function then you would have more control over when to call the event handler.

1. Create a handler function for the event
2. When pushing to the global timers array, remember to store a name and the timer id.
3. If the event occured before the timer was called through setInterval, stop the timer and call the handler directly.

Example:

```
function coolEventHandler () {
  console.log('handling cool event');
}

timers[0] = { name: 'coolEvent', id: setInterval(coolEventHandler, 15000) };

if('coolEvent') {
  // find the correct timer
  timer = timers.find(t => t.name === 'coolEvent');
  // stop the timer so the callback is never invoked
  // you probably want to remove it from the global timers array here too.
  clearInterval(timer.id);
  // call the handler directly
  coolEventHandler();
 }
```